# Moving an image to the tapped location - iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, animation, sdk

I want to make an app which contains an image, and when a user
taps, a new image should come and hide a part of the old image.

For example, there is an image contains a table, when a user taps
a cell of the table, a new image should appear and cover the taped
cell along with all the cells that are to the right and below the 
selected cell.

How can I do this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Core Animation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have a look and I hope I get an answer :)